# Slowness in update query using inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the below query to update one column based on the conditions it is specified. I am using "inner join" but it is taking more than 15 seconds to run the query even if it has to update no records(0 records).

```
UPDATE CONFIGURATION_LIST
SET DUPLICATE_SERIAL_NUM = 0
FROM CONFIGURATION_LIST
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT APPLIED_MAT_CODE, APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER, COUNT(*) AS NB
            FROM CONFIGURATION_LIST
            WHERE
                PLANT = '0067'
                AND APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER IS NOT NULL 
                AND APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER !=''
                AND DUPLICATE_SERIAL_NUM = 1
            GROUP BY 
                APPLIED_MAT_CODE, APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER
            HAVING
                COUNT(*) = 1) T2 ON T2.APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER = CONFIGURATION_LIST.APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER
                                 AND T2.APPLIED_MAT_CODE = CONFIGURATION_LIST.APPLIED_MAT_CODE
WHERE 
    CONFIGURATION_LIST.PLANT = '0067'
    AND DUPLICATE_SERIAL_NUM = 1
```

The index is there with `APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER` and `APPLIED_MAT_CODE` and fragmentation is also fine.

Could you please help me on the above query performance.

Comment: using having is bad, is distinct really needed here, do you really need a subquery? How long does the subquery need? You want to mark duplicates based on a CODE and a SERIAL_NUMBER. Or better you want to drop duplicate marks. It might be better to use an extra table. What is the unique index into your configuration LIST? You double select on PLANT=0067 and the DUPLICATE_SERIAL_NUM.

Comment: as you select on PLANT, how about an index on PLANT?

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need the `DISTINCT` when using `GROUP BY`.  SQL Server probably ignores it, but it is a bad idea anyway:

```
UPDATE CONFIGURATION_LIST
SET DUPLICATE_SERIAL_NUM = 0
    FROM CONFIGURATION_LIST INNER JOIN
         (SELECT APPLIED_MAT_CODE, APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER, COUNT(*) AS NB
          FROM CONFIGURATION_LIST cl
          WHERE cl.PLANT = '0067' AND
                cl.APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER IS NOT NULL AND
                cl.APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER <> ''
                cl.DUPLICATE_SERIAL_NUM = 1
          GROUP BY cl.APPLIED_MAT_CODE, cl.APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER
          HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
         ) T2
         ON T2.APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER = CONFIGURATION_LIST.APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER AND
            T2.APPLIED_MAT_CODE = CONFIGURATION_LIST.APPLIED_MAT_CODE
WHERE CONFIGURATION_LIST.PLANT = '0067' AND
      DUPLICATE_SERIAL_NUM = 1;
```

For this query, you want the following index:  `CONFIGURATION_LIST(PLANT, DUPLICATE_SERIAL_NUM, APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER, APPLIED_MAT_CODE, APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER)`.

The `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` suggests that you might really want `NOT EXISTS` (which would normally be faster).  But you don't really explain what the query is supposed to be doing, you only say that this code is slow.

Comment: even after removing distinct from the sub query and  adding count(colname) instead of count(*) in the subquery it does not improve the performance.actually the sub query does not take much time to execute to fetch the records.Problem comes wen the entire query runs

Comment: As the answer stated, SQL Server would most likely ignore the `DISTINCT`, so removing it should not impact performance.  (But it does make the query more readable.  You should keep it removed, regardless of its (non)impact on performance.)  Also, changing `count(*)` to count of anything is immaterial.  What's being counted is defined by the rest of the query, so what's inside the parentheses doesn't matter.  Again, no impact on performance.  What you didn't seem to do was implement the specified covering index.  That *should* impact performance.  Also look at `NOT EXISTS` like the answer said.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're checking the table for rows  that exist in the same table with the same values, and if not, update the duplicate column to zero. If your table has a unique key (identity field or composite key), you could do something like this:

```
UPDATE C
SET C.DUPLICATE_SERIAL_NUM = 0
FROM 
  CONFIGURATION_LIST C
where 
  not exists (
    select
      1 
    FROM
      CONFIGURATION_LIST C2
    where
      C2.APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER = C.APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER and
      C2.APPLIED_MAT_CODE = C.APPLIED_MAT_CODE and
      C2.UNIQUE_KEY_HERE != C.UNIQUE_KEY_HERE
  ) and 
  C.PLANT = '0067' and
  C.DUPLICATE_SERIAL_NUM = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try with a select first:

```
select APPLIED_MAT_CODE, APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER, count(*) as n
from CONFIGURATION_LIST cl
where
    cl.PLANT='0067' and
    cl.APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER IS NOT NULL and
    cl.APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER <> ''
group by APPLIED_MAT_CODE, APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER;
```

How many rows do you get with this and how long does it take?

If you remove your DUPLICATE_SERIAL_NUM column from your table it might be very simple. The DUPLICATE_SERIAL_NUM suggests that you are searching for duplicates. As you count your rows you could introduce a simple table that contains the counts:

```
create table CLCOUNT ( N int unsigned, C int /* or what APPLIED_MAT_CODE is */, S int /* or what APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER is */, PLANT char(20) /* or what PLANT is */, index unique (C,S,PLANT), index(PLANT,N));
insert into CLCOUNT select count(*), cl.APPLIED_MAT_CODE, cl.APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER, cl.PLANT
from CONFIGURATION_LIST cl
where
    cl.PLANT='0067' and
    cl.APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER IS NOT NULL and
    cl.APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER <> ''
group by APPLIED_MAT_CODE, APPLIED_SERIAL_NUMBER;
```

How long does this take?

Now you can simply `select * from CLCOUNT where PLANT='0067' and N=1;`

This is all far from being perfect. But you should be able to analyze (EXPLAIN SELECT ...) your queries and find why it takes so long.